# javascript single quotes being escaped

Tags: javascript, escaping, cs-cart

A guy I'm helping out is using an ecommerce CMS (CSCart).  Their code is escapes single quotes for security reasons I presume (I'm not very good with js).

```
<script>
function share_click()
{

  RPXNOW.loadAndRun(['Social'], function () {  <--- This line gets escaped around social
    var activity = new RPXNOW.Social.Activity(
       "Share your comment",
       "commented on 'Like My New Perfume?' on cuteoverload.com",  <--- This line as well
       "http://cuteoverload.com/2009/10/26/like-my-new-perfume/");

    RPXNOW.Social.publishActivity(activity,
      {finishCallback:function(data){
        window.location = "http://google.com/"
      }
    });
  });

}
</script>
```

Any ideas how I can work around this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "escaped"?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: 'Social' = \'Social\'  when I inspect the hosted code

Comment: What happens if you use double quotes there?

Comment: Or `function share_click() { var arr = ["Social"];   RPXNOW.loadAndRun(arr),...`

Comment: boo... I thought I tried double quotes before asking.  Guess not.  Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use double quotes. If your example is accurate, the double quotes around "http://google.com/" don't get escaped, right? So, problem solved.

And as to the single quotes inside the double-quoted string, do these cause problems if they're escaped? I tried, but I can't find a difference in behaviour whether those inner quotes are escaped or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

```
 &apos;
```

instead of  '

Or as someone else had commented the \' usually keeps the apostrophe from breaking.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<script>
function share_click() {
  var arr = ["Social"];

  RPXNOW.loadAndRun(arr, function () {  
    var activity = new RPXNOW.Social.Activity(
       "Share your comment",
       "commented on `Like My New Perfume?` on cuteoverload.com",  
       "http://cuteoverload.com/2009/10/26/like-my-new-perfume/");

    RPXNOW.Social.publishActivity(activity,
      {finishCallback:function(data){
        window.location = "http://google.com/"
      }
    });
  });

}
</script>
```